# Android: Expandable list with buttons in parent group

Tags: android, button, customization, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm trying to make an expandable list view where there is a button on the parent group that when pressed will allow the user to add an item to the child group. However I'm getting a problem when adding the button, the parent drop down sublist functionality stops working. (Ideally clicking the button adds an element clicking anywhere else causes the menu to drop down)
I copypasta'd a expandable list template and got it working before trying anything else.

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/groupname" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="40dip">
     <TextView android:id="@+id/tvGroupName" 
        android:layout_width="225dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dip" 
        android:textSize="16sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:paddingLeft="30dip" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
     </TextView>

     <Button
     android:id="@+id/addPhrase"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="+" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thats the xml for the parent group (all I changed).

The onCreate method where the expanders and collapsers are set. (The groups and children are prepopulated)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.group_indicator);

    expList = getExpandableListView();
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    //this code for adjusting the group indicator into right side of the view
    expList.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetDipsFromPixel(50), width -   GetDipsFromPixel(10));
    expList.setGroupIndicator(d);
    expList.setAdapter(new ExpAdapter(this));

expList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener()
{
@Override
public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) 
{
 Log.e("onGroupExpand", "OK");
}
});

expList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener()
{
@Override
public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) 
{
 Log.e("onGroupCollapse", "OK");
}
});

expList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()
{
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
  int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
 Log.e("OnChildClickListener", "OK");
 return false;
}
});
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have had this problem too: As soon as I add a button to the parent group, the collapse/expand function stops working. I have not been able to figure out why yet, but it's good to know there is some consistency about this happening!

Comment: Here is an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12818331/423105 'When I set these widgets [children of group item] to non clickable and non focusable the click on my group items perform [expand/collapse] normally.
... if someone has a similar problem, keep in mind to check if any of your view inside your group item is clickable or focusable and set them to android:clickable="false" android:focusable="false"'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android :- Custom ExpandableListView : cannot expand group item to display child item in CustomListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799800/android-custom-expandablelistview-cannot-expand-group-item-to-display-child)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and finally it worked when I put the button (in your case, addPhrase, as not focusable.

Here is the code I have in getGroupView of my ExpandableListAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_pathologies_header, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListPathologiesHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    lblListHeader.setCompoundDrawablePadding(30);
    lblListHeader.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
    lblListHeader.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(isExpanded ? R.drawable.up50 : R.drawable.down50, 0, 0, 0);


    FloatingActionButton fabDrug = (FloatingActionButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fab_drug);
    fabDrug.setFocusable(false);
    if (isExpanded) {
        fabDrug.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fabDrug.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NewDrugDialogFragment newFragment = NewDrugDialogFragment.newInstance(_patientId);
                newFragment.show(((Activity) _context).getFragmentManager(), "Title");
            }
        });
    } else {
        fabDrug.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    return convertView;
}
```

and it works fine, now the groups collapse and expanded as should.