# Android :- Custom ExpandableListView : cannot expand group item to display child item in CustomListView

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, expandablelistview

I'm trying to implement a custom ExpandableListView inside a SherlockFragment. I followed this [sample](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/25/android-practice-custom-expandablelistview-sample-2/) to extend BaseExpandableListAdapter and create my custom adapter.

**Here is my problem, when my expandable list is displayed on the screen I can see all the group item, but when I click on one of them, the child item which are supposed to be displayed below it don't show up**.

1. I tried to debug it, the onGroupExpandListener I put in the adapter is never called, and actually I put breakpoints in the different methods of my adapter, there are not called ever when I click on one of the group item.
2. I tried to modify my xml files which define the group item and the child item, to make them clickable or focus-able, nothing changed. I also tried to remove the editText, Button, and CheckBox I put in there, thinking it was may be creating a conflict ...
3. I thought the problem was may be due to some incompatibility issues using ExpandableListView with SherlockFragment, but according to the developer's [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/VxD_FS9wzas) its not.

So I really don't know where to look now, it's may be simply a rookie mistake I did in my adapter...
Any help would be great,

Thanks in advance!

---

here is my code:

```
public class BuildingExpandalbeListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
private SideEntity[] mSidesCollection;
private int[] groupStatus;

public BuildingExpandalbeListAdapter(Context pContext,
        ExpandableListView pExpandableListView,
        SideEntity[] pSidesCollection) {
    mContext = pContext;
    mSidesCollection = pSidesCollection;
    mExpandableListView = pExpandableListView;
    groupStatus = new int[mSidesCollection.length];
    mExpandableListView.setClickable(true);     
    setListEvent();
}

private void setListEvent() {

    mExpandableListView
            .setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    groupStatus[arg0] = 1;
                }
            });

    mExpandableListView
            .setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    groupStatus[arg0] = 0;
                }
            });
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mSidesCollection[groupPosition].getSegmentEntity(childPosition)
            .getName();
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mSidesCollection[groupPosition].getSegmentEntity(childPosition)
            .getId();
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ChildHolder childHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.building_list_item, null);

        childHolder = new ChildHolder();

        childHolder.editText1 = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        childHolder.checkBox1 = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(childHolder);
    } else {
        childHolder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    childHolder.editText1.setText(mSidesCollection[groupPosition]
            .getSegmentEntity(childPosition).getName());
    childHolder.checkBox1.setChecked(mSidesCollection[groupPosition]
            .getSegmentEntity(childPosition).hasDoor());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mSidesCollection[groupPosition].getSegmentsCollection().size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mSidesCollection[groupPosition];
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mSidesCollection.length;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GroupHolder groupHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.building_list_group, null);
        groupHolder = new GroupHolder();
        groupHolder.editText1 = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        groupHolder.editText2 = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        convertView.setTag(groupHolder);
    } else {
        groupHolder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    groupHolder.editText1
            .setText(mSidesCollection[groupPosition].getName());
    groupHolder.editText2.setText(Integer
            .toString(mSidesCollection[groupPosition]
                    .getSegmentsCollection().size()));

    return convertView;
}

class GroupHolder {
    EditText editText1;
    EditText editText2;
}

class ChildHolder {
    EditText editText1;
    CheckBox checkBox1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is my SherlockFragment using this adapter :

```
public class BuildingFragment extends SherlockFragment {

private ViewGroup myViewGroup;
private View v;
private SideEntity[] mSideCollection;

private BuildingsDbAdapter buildingDataBase;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    myViewGroup = container;
    myViewGroup.removeAllViews();
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.building_data_layout, container, false);
    buildingDataBase = new BuildingsDbAdapter(getSherlockActivity());
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    buildingDataBase.open();
    mSideCollection = BuildingsDbAdapter
            .fetchSideMatchingBuildingId(CustomTabFragmentActivity.mBuildingId);
    for (int i = 0; i < mSideCollection.length; i++) {
        BuildingsDbAdapter.fetchSegmentMatchingSideId(
                mSideCollection[i].getId(), mSideCollection[i]);
    }
    ExpandableListView mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    BuildingExpandalbeListAdapter mAdapter = new BuildingExpandalbeListAdapter(
            v.getContext().getApplicationContext(), mExpandableListView,
            mSideCollection);
    mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    buildingDataBase.close();
}
}
```

and here is my xml files :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Building name: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="13dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Columbia Tower"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

   <!--  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/honeycombish_blue"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/edit_query"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" /> -->
</LinearLayout>

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:divider="@android:color/black"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:focusable="true" >
</ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

the group_item :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Side: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="13dip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Number of Segment:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="13dip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="13dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="30dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_edit_shape"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the list_item :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="30dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_edit_shape"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Name: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="13dip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Shop1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Door" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `mSidesCollection[groupPosition].getSegmentsCollection().size();` returns something different than `0`? Also I don't know if you tried, but set your views from the group layout to non focusable `android:focusable="false"`.

Comment: @Luksprog
Thanks for your quick answer, I checked `mSidesCollection[groupPosition]` according to each group item I try to click on, there is at least one segment entity inside, so `mSidesCollection[groupPosition].getSegmentsCollection().size();` would normally return at least 1. But the problem is, that no matters how many time I click on the group item or where I click on it, the method `public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)` is never called, and never are the other methods of my adapter.
I also tried to put each views inside my group layout to non focusable, but no more success.

Comment: Are you sure the `getChildrenCount` is not being called? If this is the case, something is consuming your group clicks otherwise that method should be called. Can you try making the `EditText`(and Button, all views) non focusable in code in the `getGroupView` method(`view.setFocusable(false)`)?

Comment: Just for info, I replaced the fragment inflating my custom ExpandableListView with an other fragment. This one inflate instead the ExpandableListView provided in the [code sample](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/25/android-practice-custom-expandablelistview-sample-2/) which helped me to create my adapter. Apparently this ExpandableListView works as expected, so we can rule out a conflict between ActionBarSherlock and my custom ListView. The problem is definitely somewhere in my adapter or in one of the xml files.
Like always any suggestions would be really appreciated :)

Comment: I really don't see what the problem might be. My guess is something in the layout, I advise you to strip the rows and groups items until you are left with only a simple TextView and start adding the other views and test to see if you have the same problem. If a simple TextView works but adding other widgets don't work you have the problem in the xml. Otherwise if even a simple TextView doesn't work there is something in your adapter.

Comment: @Luksprog I checked again the `getChildrenCount` is not being called. I forced all the view of my group_item to be non focusable inside the `getGroupView` method, but it's still the same. I will modify my group items to use a basic TextView and see. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I find my mistake, the problem was in fact coming from both EditText and the Button I have been using in my group items. When I **set this widgets to non clickable and non focusable** the click on my group items perform normally.

I should have detected this conflict sooner, I tried before to remove both my Button and my EditText, but i forgot that at some point I had try to add `android:clickable="true"` to my RelativeLayout (thinking it would allowed the click on my group items) but instead it has also created a conflict :/
Anyway, if someone has a similar problem, keep in mind to check if any of your view inside your group item is clickabble or focusable and set them to `android:clickable="false" android:focusable="false"`

Comment: I thought it was something in your layout. Don't forget to accept your answer.

Comment: I also have EditText. But i need to enter some text in it. Buttons and group item is clickable now. But How can i make edittext to take input. It is not taking input now.

Comment: @Bhargavi Even if you set your editText to non clickable your can set an OnClickListener to them, the only problem is to show and hide the soft keyboard you need to do that manually, using `InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);` and `mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);`. You will also need to implement a TextWatcher to detect onTextChanged. Hope it's help